# Computer shuts down unexpectedly

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, sony-vaio

I have a 3 year old sony vaio that i wanted to upgrade from Vista to Windows 7. I installed Win 7 and because it was dusty i decided to open up the laptop and dust it off with a hair dryer(cold). When I started the computer, after 2 or 3 minutes it turned off unexpectedly. I restarted it, and while Windows was loading it shut down again. It did this a couple of times and now it seems it's OK for the last 15 minutes no shut down.

Do you have any idea what can be causing the problem? Is it software or hardware? The laptop seems to be working perfectly now, and all components seem OK.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a thermal shut down, did you notice the fans were louder than usual when this occurred? It is possible there is some debris caught in the fan grill on the back of the laptop that caused it to heat up more than normal. In my experience a hair dryer does not have enough pressure to clear dust from the fans on a notebook. Just my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like an overheating issue. However I would never use a hair dryer to blow off the dust. Static electricity is a computer killer. That may have even been what caused your issue. If cleaning out dust from a computer never ever use something that is electric. Major static electricity builder. Buy an air canister (sold at many pc shops) or get yourself a nice nylon or other non static building bristle brush. and do it that way. Please don't use a hair dryer again :)

Comment: but the computer stays on from a few seconds to a couple of minutes. and the fan seems to be working. once it stayed on for more than 1 h. do you have any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: can the problem be caused by a conflict caused by some widows 7 driver?

Comment: Really it can be any of the above. It could be that the comp just can't handle Win7. Since you just did the OS change. I'm sure you don't have anything important on it. I would reinstall Win7 again and see what happens. if you can log in after try and update the drivers for the laptop, such as video driver, sound driver, basically go to the Sony website and download all the updates you see for your model. then see what happens. After that If it is still doing that then it is a hardware issue.

Comment: if the computer shuts down before the "starting windows" image apears can that mean that its sth related to the bios? does this exclude any software/driver cause?

Comment: Have you been able to get it to startup at all? even before the hairdryer thing?

Comment: i tried two times to install just now win xp, and at the moment when if is saying "setup is starting windows" i got a blue screen. can that indicate sth? a corupted hdd?

Comment: after i installed win7 i didnt start the computer. just after i cleaned the dust

Comment: there should be an error code on the blue screen write that down next time and we can search the error code on MS site.